# How to create a custom module in vtiger 6.5 and pages

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

I created a custom module in vtiger crm version 6.5. The module was created successfully but the problem is when I click the module name a blank page appears in the view=List page.

I put the contents of vtiger version folder to module folder also language folder and change file name and class name with my module name, but how can I create view model action files according to our need?

Answer (score 0):

You can also create module from command line using below steps:

1. open the cmd prompt, go to the vtlib/tools folder and execute the Console.php file:

> ```
> >cd {YourPathToCRM}/vtlib/tools
> >php -f console.php
> ```

2. After run the command you get steps for creating various things for your CRM:

> ```
> Welcome to vTigercrm Creator.
>
> This tool will enable you to get started with developing extensions with ease.
>
> Have a good time. Press CTRL+C to "quit".
>
> Choose the options below:
>
> 1. Create New Module.
>
> 2. Create New Layout.
>
> 3. Create New Language Pack.
>
> 4. Create Test Language Pack.
>
> 5. Import Module.
>
> 6. Update Module.
>
> 7. Remove Module.
>
> Enter your choice:
> ```